# Uploading image file to google cloud bucket

Tags: php, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, fopen

Now, I want to upload an image file to gcp bucket, for that I am using this code:

```
require __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

$storage = new StorageClient();
$file = fopen($params['book']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$bucket = $storage->bucket('fingertips-books');
$object = $bucket->upload($params['book']['name'], [
    'name' => 'test.pdf'
]);
```

Where `$params` variable contains this

```
Array
    (
    [type] => PDF
    [description] => dsds
    [book] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2017-03-23.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php97AA.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 45022
        )
)
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: This I am getting

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message '{
 &quot;error&quot;: {
  &quot;errors&quot;: [
   {
    &quot;domain&quot;: &quot;global&quot;,
    &quot;reason&quot;: &quot;authError&quot;,
    &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Invalid Credentials&quot;,
    &quot;locationType&quot;: &quot;header&quot;,
    &quot;location&quot;: &quot;Authorization&quot;
   }
  ],
  &quot;code&quot;: 401,
  &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Invalid Credentials&qu

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're running on app engine using [application default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts), you'll have to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to a service account key file. See the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).